# How to scrape json data from scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I got the following response in my scrapy code:

[
[
"1-2809328194",
"SHREE RAYESHWAR INSTITUTE OF ENGINEERING AND INFORMATION TECHNOLOY",
"SHIV SHAIL, KARAI, SHIRODA, GOA 403103",
"NORTH GOA",
"Unaided - Private",
"N",
"N",
"1-13315171"
],
[
"1-2809364960",
"AGNEL INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY AND DESIGN",
"ASSAGAO,\r\nBARDEZ,\r\nGOA.",
"NORTH GOA",
"Unaided - Private",
"N",
"N",
"1-792836711"
],
[
"1-2809439609",
"GOA COLLEGE OF PHARMACY",
"18TH JUNE ROAD,PANAJI-GOA",
"NORTH GOA",
"Government",
"N",
"N",
"1-12606241"
],
[
"1-2809451721",
"GOA COLLEGE OF ART",
"ALTINHO,\r\nPANAJI - GOA\r\n403 001",
"NORTH GOA",
"Government",
"N",
"N",
"1-34323441"
],
[
"1-2809452173",
"PADRE CONCEICAO COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING",
"AGNEL GANV, VERNA, GOA - 403722",
"SOUTH GOA",
"Unaided - Private",
"N",
"N",
"1-39482811"
],
[
"1-2809476211",
"GOVERNMENT POLYTECHNIC CURCHOREM",
"OPP. KAKODA INDUSTRIAL ESTATE",
"SOUTH GOA",
"Government",
"N",
"N",
"1-453010201"
],
[
"1-2809500050",
"AGNEL INSTITUTE OF FOOD CRAFTS AND CULINARY SCIENCES",
"AGNEL TECHNICAL EDUCATION COMPLEX\r\nAGNEL ASHRAM\r\nVERNA",
"SOUTH GOA",
"Unaided - Private",
"N",
"N",
"1-473844331"
],
[
"1-2809505343",
"PONDA EDUCATION SOCIETYS RAJARAM AND TARABAI BANDEKAR COLLEGE OF PHARMACY",
"PONDA-PANAJI ROAD, FARMAGUDI, PONDA. GOA-403401",
"SOUTH GOA",
"Unaided - Private",
"N",
"N",
"1-9749331"
],
[
"1-2809601268",
"GOVERNMENT POLYTECHNIC MAYEM BICHOLIM",
"MAYEM BICHOLIM GOA",
"NORTH GOA",
"Government",
"N",
"N",
"1-455631951"
]
]

How to extract it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is nested list, with each list corresponding to single record, you  can try below approach:

```
lets say:

    records = [['1-2809328194', 'SHREE RAYESHWAR INSTITUTE OF ENGINEERING AND INFORMATION TECHNOLOY', 'SHIV SHAIL, KARAI, SHIRODA, GOA 403103', 'NORTH GOA', 'Unaided - Private', 'N', 'N', '1-13315171'], ['1-2809364960', 'AGNEL INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY AND DESIGN', 'ASSAGAO,\r\nBARDEZ,\r\nGOA.', 'NORTH GOA', 'Unaided - Private', 'N', 'N', '1-792836711']]

    for item in records:
        yield {
            field1: item[0],
            field2: item[1]
            .....
            .....
       }
```